# R: What does an object of class “call” do? What does match.call(expand.dots = FALSE) do inside new_function?

Tags: r, function

I read through a piece of code and I could not fully understand  what does mf = match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)  do. The code is as following:

```
    new_function <- function (formula, data, subset, weights, na.action 
      = na.omit, level ) 

 {
   mf <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
   m <- match(c("formula", "data", "subset", "weights", "na.action"), 
         names(mf), 0)
   mf <- mf[c(1, m)]
   mf$drop.unused.levels <- FALSE
   mf[[1]] <- as.name("model.frame")
   m <- eval.parent(mf)
   y <- model.response(m)
   x <- m[, c(-1, -which(names(m) == "(weights)")), drop = FALSE]
   w <- model.weights(m)
  .
  .
  .
  .

 }
```

If later there is a call of the function like this:

```
    results = new_function(sales~. , data = Sample_10, level =3)
```

what will match.call(expand.dots = FALSE) behaves inside the function?

Thank you.

Comment: Does `new_function <- function (formula, data, subset)  match.call(expand.dots = FALSE); new_function(sales~. , data, level)` answer your question? Does `help("match.call")` answer your question? If not, can you explain in more detail what you are asking?

Comment: From the doc, match.call will allow new_function  ignores some missing argument.So while calling new_function(sales~. , data = Sample_10, level =3), what will mf <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE) inside function will be? names(mf) is like  ("formula","data","level")?

Comment: My previous comment clearly demonstrate how you can check that.

Comment: How could we manipulate  an class of object call? How could I see it's attribute? like here mf?

Comment: I think you need to describe your actual problem. If you want a general explanation, you might have luck with [Hadley's book](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/).

Comment: This Hadley's book is good.  Thanks.